# Finding row that causes error from csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am trying to work with a data set from a csv file. When I try to take the numbers from the file and convert them from strings to floats I am getting an error

```
could not convert string to float:
```

Does anyone know a way I could search for where the error is in my file?

I have looked for obvious spaces or empty lines and have not found anything, so I am hoping there is a way to narrow down my search. Something like listing the row number where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just print the line (temporarily, for debugging purposes) before converting to float.

Or, a better course of action, would be adding an [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), example:

```
for line in f:
    try:
        # float conversion here
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Error happened on line '%s'" % line)
        print(e)
```